# How to check that byte array is Base64 encoded?

Tags: java

How to check that byte array is Base64 encoded?

I have an array of bytes, which I need to test if it is base64 encoded.

Comment: Do you know what the unencoded byte array should contain?  The only way to check is to unencode it and see if you get back what you had originally.

Comment: You cannot distinguish between something that *looks* like Base64 and something that actually *is* Base64. You need to keep track of the metadata to be sure.

Answer (score 10):

You can use apache's [Base64.isBase64(byte[])](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#isBase64-byte:A-) method:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

...

boolean isBase64 = Base64.isBase64(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Base64-encoded strings have length divisible by 4, and consist of characters `A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, `0`-`9`, `+`, and `/`. If your array of bytes has length that is not divisible by 4, or contains bytes that map to characters outside these ranges, then it does not represent a Base64-encoded string; otherwise, your array of bytes represents a valid Base-64 encoded string.

Comment: This is only if byte array was produced by `String.getBytes(encoding)`, write? Also, we do not know which encoding was used. So I would say it is not cleat what OP wants

Comment: @Andremoniy You are right about `String.getBytes` assumption, and also the assumption of the correct encoding. I think it's quite clear what OP *wants*, but it's not clear what OP *has* :-)

Comment: Base64 is not a *single* standard encoding. There are multiple dialects (partially compatible). Padding is, for example, optional in many contexts. There is also more than one possible alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64