# How to check is InputStream Base64 encoded? (without converting to bytes)

Tags: java, base64, inputstream

Let's imagine, that I have a large file to be processed and I do not want to load it into the memory by converting it to bytes(or string).

So I have `InputStream` instead.

The question, is there any way to check whether this `InputStream` is `Base64` encoded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check that byte array is Base64 encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226385/how-to-check-that-byte-array-is-base64-encoded)

Comment: No, I do not have a byte array. And I do not want to get it from InputStream, because file size could be too large.

Comment: You can never tell for sure. But if you read for example the first 500 bytes and every byte of these 500 converts to `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` `+` or `/` the probability that it's Base64 Encoded is pretty high

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luca's reference, you might also want to check this out: [How to check whether a string is Base64 encoded or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571501/how-to-check-whether-a-string-is-base64-encoded-or-not)

The [regular expression search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571649/9983575) should work for your constraint of not converting to bytes since regular expressions just scan your document for character matches. There's also a built-in [common-codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217969/9983575) and the [java.util.Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35820078/9983575) libraries.

Are these answers more along the lines of what you were looking for?

Comment: I've already checked that articles, but the issue is I cannot upload into the memory whole file. String is not a solution, because file could be 1GB, for example, and what if there are 1000 users would upload such files? I cannot work with anything except InputStream to save memory and to process faster.

Comment: Hmm in that case using the [Scanner](https://stackabuse.com/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-java/) class comes to mind. Would iterating through the file line by line along with a check on that specific line work? If so you could just iterate through the file using something like `String line = scanner.nextLine();` and then run the regular expression on `line`

Comment: @ShailShouryya and what is a `line`in a base64 file? If it's really base64, then there are usually no linebreaks ´\n` in the file.